# Will an integer divided by 100 ever cause floating point errors in PHP?

Tags: php, math, floating-point

I'm always wary of adding and subtracting floating point numbers, as they can cause some errors when truncating instead of round.

My question though: will an integer divided by 100 ever cause floating point errors in PHP?

I.e. is it "safe", should I always rely on `round($x / 100, 2)`?

Comment: Only 4 values in every 100 won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Actually, since 100 isn't a power of two, the result of `$x / 100` will *always* be inexact unless `$x` is a multiple of 25. (You get 4 for free since 4 is a power of 2.)